How to resolve mongocxx driver parse error?
Installed mongocxx driver version 3.10.1 on linux using tarball from github(also installed mongo-c driver version 1.27.5).
For installation i used below commands for mongo-c driver:
tar -xzf mongo-c-driver.tar.gz
cd mongo-c-driver-1.27.5/  
mkdir cmake-build 
cd cmake-build/  
cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF -DENABLE_MONGODB_AWS_AUTH=OFF -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/bin/openssl  .. 
make  
sudo make install

And for the mongocxx driver used below commands:
tar -xzf mongo-cxx-driver-r3.10.1.tar.gz 
cd mongo-cxx-driver-r3.10.1/build 
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DMONGOCXX_OVERRIDE_DEFAULT_INSTALL_PREFIX=OFF     -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 
cmake --build .
sudo cmake --build . --target install

I use it with qt c++ development with mongodb. But after including the mongocxx and bsoncxx .hpp files i get

parse error at /.../include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/enums/binary_sub_type.hpp                        types.hp 68

on qt creator. Also says in the detail of the error:

File not found /local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/types.hp

yes not ".hpp" it says "types.hp"  . I get this while building my application.
I can see the included .hpp source files of mongocxx and bsoncxx from my .cpp code. Library paths and includings also made on the .pro file of the project as below. Not getting any error from it.
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi \
               /usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
LIBS        += -L/usr/local/lib64 -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx

And i included below classes:
mongocxx/client.hpp
mongocxx/uri.hpp
mongocxx/instance.hpp
mongocxx/database.hpp
mongocxx/collection.hpp
bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp

How can i resolve this error?
Tried to build my qt c++ application and got this error from qt creator.

Problem solved by moving #include parts of mongocxx related classes to the .cpp files.

In the official documentation first they recommend to use pkg-config to get all the correct compilation flags. Check the output of
pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx

most likely there are more required include directories (on my Ubuntu there is also /usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/third_party/mnmlstc).
Now to use the output of pkg-config with your Qt Creator you don't need to copy-paste these flags in your *.pro file, instead use this:
SOURCES += main.cpp
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libmongocxx
TARGET = hello

It will allow you to compile simple hello world including mongocxx headers:
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/database.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/collection.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>

int main() {
  return 0;
}


pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx  , command gives include paths and -L/usr/local/lib64 paths for mongocxx and bsoncxx. But qmake gives error on .pro file "libmongocxx development package not found" with your configuration above

Update your question with what EXACTLY pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx command returns, and also explain how did you obtain, compiled, and installed mongocxx. In detail, form wget xxx.zip to sudo make install. Then in detail explain your Qt project structure and the commands you use to configure and compile the project. The solution I posted works with both Qt5 and Qt6, on different systems (Ubuntu, Debian, Oracle), so you are clearly missing some dependencies.

pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx ,  I resolved it exporting path to the  $PKG_CONFIG_PATH  , but still get parse error, also added some deatils on installation
